# Should I strip the XML declaration from suds output before parsing with lxml?

Tags: python, unicode, soap, lxml, suds

I’m trying to implement a SOAP webservice in Python 2.6 using the [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) library. That is working well, but I’ve run into a problem when trying to parse the output with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/).

Suds returns a `suds.sax.text.Text` object with the reply from the SOAP service. The `suds.sax.text.Text` class is a subclass of the Python built-in [Unicode class](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-objects.htm). In essence, it would be comparable with this Python statement:

```
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root><lotsofelements \></root>'
```

Which is incongrous, since if the XML declaration is correct, the contents are UTF-8 encoded, and thus *not* a Python Unicode object (because those are stored in some internal encoding like UCS4).

lxml will refuse to parse this, [as documented](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html#python-unicode-strings), since there is no clear answer to what encoding it should be interpreted as.

As I see it, there are two ways out of this bind:

1. Strip the `<?xml>` declaration, including the encoding.
2. Convert the output from Suds into a bytestring, using the specified encoding.

Currently, the data I’m receiving from the webservice is within the ASCII-range, so either way will work, but both feels very much like ugly hacks to me, and I’m not quite sure what would happen, if I start to receive data that would need a wider range of Unicode characters.

Any good ideas? I can’t imagine I’m the first one in this position…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You and lxml are correct; a valid XML document must be a stream of bytes encoded as declared in the `<?xml .....` header (default: UTF-8).

I'd suggest a third option: leave it in unicode with an XML header that omits the encoding declaration but leaves the version in there (future-safe). That will keep lxml happy and avoid the overhead of you encoding it again.

I'd also suggest some gentle enquiry at the suds site and having a poke around in their source.

Comment: I suppose simply removing the encoding part is a reasonable way to go about it, thanks.

I think I’ll hit up the suds guys to see if a fix for this edge case is worthy of inclusion into the main library.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm currently implementing my first Suds-based solution and parsing my responses with lxml without a problem, but I think this could be because I'm doing it in a pretty blunt and dumb way. Here's what my code looks like:

```
try:
    result = self.client.service.ExportOwnersDetails(fAccess=self.access_id, fParams=params)
except URLError:
    # TODO: Log timeout here, handle
    return
response = str(result.fReturn)

if len(response) == 0 or response.find('<?xml ') == -1:
    # TODO: Log import error here, handle
    return
response = StringIO(response)
xml = etree.parse(response)
```

Like I said, not very clever (and obviously I still have some logging to do), but that's my approach. The fAccess, fParams, fReturn nonsense is the naming convention at the third-party provider I'm integrating with.

Comment: Well, you could use `etree.fromstring(response)` instead of having to convert to a StringIO first (etree.parse() is for reading files, etree.fromstring() happily accepts strings).
But the StringIO conversion may be the reason you’re not seeing the same errors I do…

Comment: Duh, I knew I'd been away from lxml too long. fromstring() worked fine for me. Thanks for asking a question so you could clean up my code.